# How to get last date output in web form application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I was given a task to make a web form application where user inputs a date and the application returns the last date of that month as output.Please help me to build this. Do I have to use EOMONTH?

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '12/1/2011';  
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date ) AS Result;  
GO
```

I am an absolute beginner. It will mean a lot for me if you tell me the step by step procedure.

Comment: Why do you need to call SQL to do this from an Application? There's no reason to use SQL Server, as I'm confident that, regardless of the language you're using, you'll be able to determine the last day of the month in your application's language.

Comment: ok, points taken. The language is C#

Comment: Using `C#` this should give you the last date for the month - 
`DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)`

Answer (score 0):

References [DateTime Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx), [TextBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), [Label Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime tempDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(userInputTextBox.Text, out tempDate))
{
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month));
    endOfMonthLabel.text = newDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
}
else
{
    endOfMonthLabel.text = "invalid date format";
}
```

Comment: Thank you .Please tell me the step by step procedure to make a web form application in visual studio which will use this code to show the last date as an output

Comment: This will be a good place to start so you can learn about asp.net web forms. https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.DaysInMonth(2018,06)

Should give you the last dare as 30